# Как правильно сделать загрузку связанных данных во Fluent API C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Есть две связанные таблицы внешним ключем.
В первом контролере осуществляется отправка файла и добавление его в базу данных. Во втором добавленый файл разбивается на слайды и считается.Вопрос в том,как сделать,чтобы при добавлении слайды автоматически брали id файла.
Вот как добавляю слайды в БД (пока что без IdPres)

```
 var slide = new SlideDb { TextSlide = text, UuidSlide = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()  };
                _context.Add(slide);
                _context.SaveChanges();
```

Весь контекст базы данных

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PresentationDb>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.IdPres);

            entity.ToTable("PresentationDB");

            entity.Property(e => e.DescPres)
                .HasMaxLength(600)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.NamePres)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(400)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.UuidPres)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SlideDb>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.UuidSlide);

            entity.ToTable("SlideDB");

            entity.Property(e => e.UuidSlide)
                .HasMaxLength(300)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.IdSlide).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.TextSlide).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.TitleSlide)
                .HasMaxLength(300)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdPresNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.SlideDb)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdPres)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_SlideDB_PresentationDB");
        });
    }
```

Класс Файла (презентации)

```
 public partial class PresentationDb
{
    public PresentationDb()
    {
        SlideDb = new HashSet<SlideDb>();
    }

    public int IdPres { get; set; }
    public string NamePres { get; set; }
    public string UuidPres { get; set; }
    public string DescPres { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SlideDb> SlideDb { get; set; }
}
```

Класс Слайдов

```
public partial class SlideDb
{
    public int IdSlide { get; set; }
    public int IdPres { get; set; }
    public string UuidSlide { get; set; }
    public string TextSlide { get; set; }
    public string TitleSlide { get; set; }

    public PresentationDb IdPresNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код классов `файл` и `слайд`, надо посмотреть, используете ли вы навигационные свойства. Если используете, просто добавляйте слайд к загруженному файлу и затем вызывайте `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko обновил

Comment: @Yaroslav я посмотрел,но возникают ошибки.Я немного не понимаю логики

Comment: @Yaroslav я делал через явную загрузку, и в итоге ничего так и не добавилось

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83425/discussion-between-richardgir-and-yaroslav).

Comment: @Yaroslav а IdPres - это что по-вашему? Кроме того, EF умеет и сама ключи создавать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы слайд добавлялся именно к файлу - его надо связывать с файлом, а не просто в БД складывать.

Способ первый:

```
slide = new SlideDb { IdPresNavigation = ... };
_context.Add(slide);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Способ второй (требует предварительной загрузки слайдов):

```
var pres = ...;
pres.SlideDb.Add(slide);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @PavelMayorov так а чему он может равняться, если он первичный ключ и автоинкрементный? не понимаю,в чем заключается ваш первый способ

Comment: @richardgir у вас что, всего один файл в БД?

Comment: @PavelMayorov по идее она вообще пустая изначально.С добавлением файла, его ID инкрементируется, потом добавляются слайды и записывают ID , чтобы понимать из какого файла какие слайды

Comment: @richardgir ну так этот файл, чей id вы собрались записывать, и нужно указать

Comment: @PavelMayorov так и как же мне это указать?Исходя из того я и не понял ваш 1 способ.  вопрос в этом и состоял.

Comment: @richardgir вам надо заполнить свойство IdPresNavigation объектом, из которого EF сможет взять нужный ID. Что именно тут непонятно?

Comment: так какой объект указывать.Я у вас это и пытаюсь выяснить!!! Если я пытаюсь указать путь к файлу, тогда выведет ошибку. Если у IdPresNavigation тип PresentationDB,объект какого типа вставлять

Comment: @richardgir вставляйте объект типа PresentationDB

Comment: и он не валиден в контексте `slide = new SlideDb { ... };`

Comment: @richardgir что значит "не валиден"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83437/discussion-between-richardgir-and-pavel-mayorov).